# Get Substring of a string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a string like `****_xxx.$$$$.20210909_&&&` .I want to get exact 20210909 this as the result.

I have tried few options with substring and it did not solve my problem. Please suggest any better methods.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your format, you could use:

```
select left(right(str, 12), 8)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method of selecting the desired string is to use `parsename`.

```
select left(parsename(@str,1), 8) desired_substring
```

Please see the db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=199b5cfcaa676c0be4a46c25cabb3359).

Read more about that from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).